# Fancy Upload does not work with mootools 1.4.1 due to fade/tween errors

Tags: javascript, html, mootools, multifile-uploader, mootools-events

I am trying to integrate [Fancy Uploads "Queued Photo Uploader"](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/photoqueue/) into my website but the `Clear List` and  `Start Upload` click events are not firing.

I have stripped out all of my code and resorted to copying and pasting the working example from the [queued upload demo](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/3-0/showcase/photoqueue/) - but I cannot get these events to fire.

Can anyone see what I have missed and why the `click` events are not firing?

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ywzWM/1/**

**Note: Fancy Uploads uses the Mootools framework.**

---

#### Edit

Sorry - the issue has been resolved. I had not included all of the required HTML as I had copied and pasted from the site and I believe Fancy Upload removes 'fall back' HTML which must be required on page load.

**Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ywzWM/2/**

---

#### New question

Fancy Uploader does not work as expected using Mootools 1.4.1. When a single image is removed from the queue, it is `hidden` rather than `removed` - so the element still holds space on the page.

This only occurs in version 1.4.1 (element is removed in all versions down to 1.2.2 and in the new 1.4.2 release). Does anyone know what significant thing was changed in version 1.4.1 to cause this?

The reason I ask is because the [Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#mootools) still has Mootools 1.4.1 listed as the latest version, so others may run into this issue.

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ywzWM/3/** 

[uses version 1.4.1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. 1.4.1 has a bug in `Element.fade` - in fact, several bugs.

breaks behavior of `.fade(0,1)`:
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2125

Element.fade does not set visibility anymore:
https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2074

you can do what I do - grab the [Element.fade](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Fx/Fx.Tween.js#L70-95) code from github and do `Element.implement({ fade: ... });` in your own sources after mootools loads - until google update their API to 1.4.2.

on the latter, I have already requested they update several times (2-3 days ago) - release was on friday last week so it's been nearly a week. it won't be long now, hopefully...